# Show list of taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type with two taxonomies, project-type and project-name. I am trying to display a list of project-names with links when the project-type is photography. The code I have so far is

```
<?php
    if(is_taxonomy('photography')) 
    {
        $taxonomy = 'project-name';
        $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) 
                {
                    echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
                }
    }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

If I remove the if then it displays all the project-names but I need it to show only the ones that also have the project-type 'photography'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about taxonomy of taxonomy ????

Comment: The custom post type has two taxonomies.

Answer (score 1):

Check this...

```
$term = get_term_by('name', 'photography', 'project-type');
if($term != false ){
    $taxonomy = 'project-name';
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term)
        {
            echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted...